# Move several columns to become rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Name   Cost   Total1    
Joe    5      10        
Bob    7      15        
Tom    20     1
```

I want to more column Total1 and Total2 to become row for each record and expect result

```
Name   Cost   Total1    
Joe    5
Joe           10        
Bob    7 
Bob           15        
Tom    20
Tom           1
```

My query

```
select Name, cost, total1
  indicatorname,
  indicatorvalue
from mytable
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in (total1)
) unpiv;
```

I don't think it's working. Not sure how to maker it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `values` constructor with `cross apply` to create split into multiple rows:

```
select T.name, v.Cost, v.Total1
from T cross apply (values
    (1, Cost, null),
    (2, null, Total1)
) v(n, Cost, Total1)
order by T.name, v.n;
```